# Kiwi TCMS - test case tableview

Tags: testcase, kiwi-tcms

I am testing kiwi TCMS having the following markup:

Scenario: ... what behavior will be tested ...
Given ... conditions ...
When ... actions ...
Then ... expected results ...

Actions:

item
item
item
Expected results:

item
item
item
Notes:

basically when this is rendered you get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUtNr.png)

is there anyway to show the tescase int the format

Step | result

in a nice table way

I am trying this this simpleMDE markup but it is not rendering a table

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| John     | Doe      | Male     |
| Mary     | Smith    | Female   |

it is just showing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix in master branch, not yet released, see https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/816